# By-ref arguments: is this an inconsistency between std::thread and std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::bind` and `std::thread` share a few design principles. Since both of them store local objets corresponding to the passed arguments, we need to use either `std::ref` or `std::cref` if reference semantics is desired:

```
void f(int& i, double d) { /*...*/ }

void g() {
    int x = 10;
    std::bind(f, std::ref(x), _1) (3.14);
    std::thread t1(f, std::ref(x), 3.14);
    //...
}
```

But I'm intrigued by a recent personal discovery: `std::bind` will allow you to pass a value in the case above, even though this is not what one usually wants.

```
    std::bind(f, x, _1) (3.14); // Usually wrong, but valid.
```

However, this is not true for `std::thread`. The following will trigger a compile error.

```
    std::thread t2(f, x, 3.14); // Usually wrong and invalid: Error!
```

At first sight I thought this was a compiler bug, but the error is indeed legitimate. It seems that the templated version of `std::thread`'s constructor is not able to correctly deduce the arguments due to the [copy decaying](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) *requirement* (tranforming `int&` in `int`) imposed by 30.3.1.2.

The question is: Why not require something similar to `std::bind`'s arguments? Or is this **apparent** inconsistency intended?

Note: Explained why it's not a duplicated in the comment below.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. *That* question is explaining what is the premisse of *my* question. Also, it's doesn't touch std::thread. In fact, what I'm pointing is a counter-example of one of the comments there (about std::thread's constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function object returned by `bind` is designed for reuse (i.e., call be called multiple times); it therefore must pass its bound arguments as lvalues, because you don't want to move from said arguments or later calls would see a moved-from bound argument. (Similarly, you want the function object to be called as an lvalue, too.)

This concern is inapplicable to `std::thread` and friends. The thread function will only be called once, with the provided arguments. It's perfectly safe to move from them because nothing else is going to be looking at them. They are effectively temporary copies, made just for the new thread. Thus the function object is called as an rvalue and the arguments are passed as rvalues.

Comment: ^^ This. And because of the reasons in the first paragraph, you can use the result of `std::bind` as a stateful function object, because it has non-static data members that can be passed to the target object and modified, and retain state between calls. Mutable lambdas have a similar property for variables captured by copy. This is by design and not a flaw in `std::bind`.

Answer (score 6):

`std::bind` was mostly obsolete when it arrived due to the existence of lambdas.  With C++14 improvements and C++17 `std::apply`, the remaining use cases for `bind` are pretty much gone.

Even in C++11 the cases where `bind` solved a problem that a lambda did not solve where relatively rare.

On the other hand, `std::thread` was solving a slightly different problem.  It doesn't need the flexibility of `bind` to "solve every issue", instead it could block what would usually be bad code.

In the `bind` case The reference passed to `f` won't be `x` but rather a reference to an internal stored copy of `x`.  This is extremely surprising.

```
void f(int& x) {
    ++x;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
};

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    auto b = std::bind(f, x);
    b();
    b();
    b();
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

prints

```
1
2
3
0
```

where the last `0` is the original `x`, while `1` `2` and `3` are the incremented copy of `x` stored within `f`.

With lambda, the difference between a mutable stored state and an external reference can be made clear.

```
auto b = [&x]{ f(x); };
```

vs

```
auto b = [x]()mutable{ f(x); };
```

one of which copies `x` then invokes `f` repeatedly on it, the other passes a reference to `x` into `f`.

There really isn't a way to do this with `bind` without allowing `f` to access the stored copy of `x` as a reference.

For `std::thread`, if you want this mutable local copy behavior you just use a lambda.

```
std::thread t1([x]()mutable{ f(x); });
```

In fact, I would argue most of the INVOKE syntax in C++11 seems to be a legacy of not having C++14 power lambdas and `std::apply` in the language.  There are very few cases not solved by lambda and `std::apply` (apply is needed as lambdas don't easily support moving packs into them then extracing them inside).

But we don't have a time machine, so we have these multiple parallel ways to express the idea of invoking something in a specific context in C++.

Comment: std::bind is not (until today) obsolete. That's why it's been introduced in C++11 together with lambdas. What actually became obsolete with the introduction of lambdas were things like std::mem_fn or std::bind1st (std::bind2nd). In fact, std::bind is *only* mechanism of partial function application in C++ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Comment: @LeandroT.C.Melo `[x](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){ return f(x, decltype(args)(args)...); }`  I just partly applied `x` to `f` with no use of `bind`.  More complex cases can be used in, well, more general cases.  Like binding a set of arguments.

Comment: Interesting solution. I don't think that would work (out of the box) with member functions though...? Anyways, I should have said the only *library component*. In a sense, if we think from a *de-sugaring* standpoint, we can consider a bunch of things "obsolete".

Comment: @LeandroT.C.Melo `[x,this]`.  Or `[x,bob]{ return bob->f(x, decltype(args)(args...); }` or if you need full on INVOKE, `std::invoke(f, x, decltype(args)(args)...); }`.  The point is that lambda does a really good job of binding arguments and creating code-on-the-spot.  Only at the full extent of massively generic does it get verbose, and `std::bind` doesn't work in fully generic situations due to its simply insane recursive quirks (`boost::bind` has a laundry system (forgot what it is called) to get rid of said quirk, but `std` lacks it).  Nevermind overload set issues!

Comment: Sure, I agree. But see...You need a different lambda. That's why library components are for. Not saying std::bind is perfect, but that's what we got.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can tell, `thread` started off with basically the same rules as `bind`, but was modified in 2010 by [N3090](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3090.pdf) to take on the constraint you've identified.

Using that to bisect the various contributions, I believe you're looking for [LWG issue 929](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3088.html#929).

Ironically, the intention seems to have been to make the `thread` constructor *less* constrained. Certainly there's no mention of `bind`, although [this wording was later also applied to `async`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3058.html) ("Clean-up" section after LWG 1315), so I would say `bind` got left behind.

It's quite hard to be sure, though, so I would recommend asking [the committee itself](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-discussion).